# S3 RequestTimeTooSkewed error due to local machine's clock skew

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, ntp

While working on my local machine I have been trying to upload images (which uploads them immediately to the amazon server), but it was giving me a bug (RequestTimeTooSkewed Error using PHP S3 Class), I could figure out that it's a time zone issue and that S3 uses the current time zone to authenticate request, do I need to set up or change any configuration on the EC2 server to be able to upload images locally?

Comment: It doesn't mention S3 *RequestTimeTooSkewed*, but same issue as [How to force a clock update using ntp?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254826/how-to-force-a-clock-update-using-ntp)

Answer (score 6):

Sync your clock with an NTP time server. All modern OS's support this.

Wherever you're uploading **from** is the machine that needs to be synced.

Comment: You can find a list of NTP servers here:
http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/use.html

And you can run this from your source machine ```sudo ntpdate 0.pool.ntp.org```

Answer (score 3):

Check your time synchronization on your ec2 instance. Due to the nature of virtual machines, the clock can skew over time. S3 does not allow requests that are more than a few minutes off.

Answer (score 1):

Running code from a virtual machine, had to do `sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com` to sync, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the ntp service usually fixes this:

```
sudo service ntpd restart
```

See also: [How to force a clock update using ntp?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254826/how-to-force-a-clock-update-using-ntp)

Answer (score 0):

sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov

This will set your local machines time to current time... you can change your timezone after local time is correct.